# Can't start sonar on Ubuntu after upgrading

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, sonarqube

System: Ubuntu 14.04
Sonar - sonar 5.0.1 installed to /opt via apt-get

After starting and waiting ~3 mins server stops.
Here is full log: http://pastebin.com/CZN29LF4

I think problem in ES, but I can't figure it out how to solve it.

Comment: Two questions to help investigating :
- did you install the zip in a fresh directory or over a previous installation ?
- what happens if you restart server ?

Comment: @SimonBrandhof a upgraded sonar with command: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. When I restart sonar - init script says all is ok, but after 3-5 mins sonar shuts down.

Comment: you should check that distribution was not unzipped over another installation. Moreover you should try to drop the directory data/es and restart.